# calender invite is not working when i create using xpages?

Tags: xpages

When I'm trying to send calender invite using xpages I'm getting the below error

i was not able to create document in mail DB.

note: mail db & application db is in different server in the same domain.

> ```
> Error: 
>
> Unexpected runtime error
> The runtime has encountered an unexpected error.
> Error source
> Page Name:/xp_Home.xsp
> Control Id: button1
> Property: onclick
>
> Exception
> Error while executing JavaScript action expression
> Script interpreter error, line=454, col=56: [TypeError] Exception occurred calling method NotesDatabase.createDocument() null
>    at [/Actions.jss].createCalendarEntry()
> ```

JavaScript code

```
function validateReq(){
  var fldFocusFlag =false
  var valid = true;
```

Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: Looks like something is `null` here, maybe the `NotesDatabase`. Please post the code of `[/Actions.jss].createCalendarEntry()`.

Comment: It really does not seem likely that you get the error in any of the three lines of JavaScript code that you have added above.... /John

Answer (score 1):

It is a little difficult to assist you further with the code at hand. From the message it appears that you may have tried to create a document using the NotesDatabase as a static class. You cannot do that. You will have to get a handle to the database where you want to create the document (a calendar entry is just an ordinary document with some fields...)

So assuming you are trying to create the document in the current database you would have to do something along these lines:

```
var db:NotesDatabase = Session.getCurrentDatabase()
var doc:NotesDocument = db.createDocument()
```

There is also a global object ready for you to give the current database right away, so you could simplify the code to:

```
var doc:NotesDocument = database.createDocument()
```

You do not have to specify the data/object type (e.g. :NotesDatabase), however, this will help the editor help you with suggestions ;-)

HTH
/John

Comment: I'm able to get the handle of the Mail DB where i have to create document. i tested this with print statements. My code is working fine if i deploy my db in my mail server.

Comment: Ok, so if the problem is that you cannot access the database on another server than the server where your database is placed, you probably need to "trust" the servers to access each other. Look in the server document, second tab ("Security") at the very bottom (to the left...). Depending on your server topology you could enter the group "LocalDomainServers" in this field. /John

Comment: Thanks i tried adding trust server too its not working. Is single sign on causing the issue?

Comment: Hmmm.... I am not sure what you are trying to do. Are you creating the calendar appointment directly in the mail database, or are you trying to send it to the user? When it does not work - what errors do you get?? /John

Answer (score 0):

You don't create calendar entries directly in a users mailfile. Most likely you don't have access to it (ACL or server remote). The correct way is to send a calendar invite to that user. See [this technote](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21229486) for field details.
You can set to not require a reply and use a policy to autoprocess notices coming from the signer id. Note: in Notes 9 there is a more complete calendar API

Comment: I tied after providing access on mail db as well. Let me check your link.